# TextBox string Dependency Property doesn't work

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls, dependency-properties

I wrote a little `string` Dependency Property for TextBox Binding in a UserControl to bind it in another one, but it won't update.

UserControl CodeBehind:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty MessageTextSendProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("MessageTextSend", typeof(string), typeof(MessagingControl),
        new PropertyMetadata(default(string)));

public string MessageTextSend
{
    get { return (string)GetValue(MessageTextSendProperty); }
    set { SetValue(MessageTextSendProperty, value); }
}
```

UserControl XAML:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=MessageTextSend,
                        RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,
                                                       AncestorType={x:Type local:MessagingControl}}}" />
```

And I'm using it like this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="SomeProject.View.ChatView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:command="http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvmlight"
         xmlns:control="clr-namespace:SomeProject.View.Control"
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
         xmlns:model="clr-namespace:SomeProject.Model"
         DataContext="{Binding Chat,
                               Source={StaticResource Locator}}"
         FontSize="15"
         d:DesignHeight="500"
         d:DesignWidth="700"
         mc:Ignorable="d">

         <control:MessagingControl Grid.Column="0"
                                   MessageBubbleCollection="{Binding MessageCollection}"
                                   MessageTextSend="{Binding Message}"
                                   SendCommand="{Binding SendMessageCommand}" />
</UserControl>
```

---

```
public string Message
{
    get { return _message; }
    set { Set(ref _message, value); }
}
```

If I'm setting the Message Property, the TextBox won't change its Text and if the TextBox Text is set via keyboard, it doesn't changes the Property too.

What could I missing?

**Edit**: Added UserControl Tag with DataContext

Comment: You probably forgot to set the DataContext of the MessagingControl (or one of its parent elements) to an instance of the view model class that has the Message property.

Comment: Looks to me like you're only binding in one direction. If you want user input in the textbox to update the DP, you'll need two-way binding. `BindingMode.TwoWay`

Comment: @Okuma.Scott The `TextBox.Text` property binds two-way by default.

Comment: Are you missing the `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` which triggers when change in `Textproperty`.  By default, it will update only on `LostFocus`

Comment: @Gopichandar Although it might make sense to set `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged`, that does not explain why "the TextBox won't change its Text" when the Message property changes.

Comment: @Clemens the answer for what you asked is already mentioned by you in comments, I agreed the same with an upvote :)

Comment: @Clemens I set the DataContext in the parent UserControl (View), where the instance MessagingControl with Binding is. Also the editor suggests me the available Properties. I'll try to set TwoWay Binding and PropertyChanged as SourceTrigger.

Comment: @Daniel As already said, the Text property of a TextBox binds two-way by default. No need to set that. UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged would only be necessary if you want that the binding source property is updated while the user is typing, i.e. on every key stroke. Otherwise it's only upated when the TextBox loses focus.

Comment: @Clemes Ok, now I know.. but the Dependency Property still doesn't work.

Comment: Could you show the code or XAML where you set the DataContext?

Comment: You do not accidentially set the DataContext in the MessagingControl constructor, e.g. by something like `DataContext = this;`?

Comment: @Clemens nope, the constructor has only the Initialize method by default

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the full working sample code.

**MessagingControl.xaml**

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=MessageTextSend, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,
                    RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,
                                                   AncestorType={x:Type local:MessagingControl}}}" />
</StackPanel>
```

**MessagingControl.xaml.cs**

```
    public MessagingControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty MessageTextSendProperty =
       DependencyProperty.Register("MessageTextSend", typeof(string), typeof(MessagingControl),
           new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(default(string), FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));

    public string MessageTextSend
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(MessageTextSendProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MessageTextSendProperty, value); }
    }
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<StackPanel>
    <local:MessagingControl MessageTextSend="{Binding Message}"  x:Name="uc"/>        
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=uc, Path=MessageTextSend}" />
</StackPanel>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = new SampleClass() { Message = "My Message" };
    }       
}

public class SampleClass
{
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I use the ServiceLocator (with Unity) for DataContext / Object Binding, because ViewFirst is overdressed for my purpose. But adding PropertyChanged doesn't worked too.

Comment: @Daniel check your `Ourput` window of VS for any `Binding Errors` .

Comment: Changing to FrameworkPropertyMetadata just worked, but why? Thanks!

Comment: @Daniel Changing the `FrameworkPropertyMetadata` is not the case why the code started working.  There should be some other thing.

Comment: @Daniel Feel free to accept the answer if it is useful to resolve your problem.  Thanks.